# What happens to data across memory pages?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, cpu

Let's say we have 64-byte pages. In the virtual memory space a 4-byte `int` is allocated at [0, 4), and we now want to allocate an array of 10 `double`. For example, if malloc decides to put the array at [4, 84), there would be one `double` going across page 0 and page 1 at [60, 68). What happens when we try to access that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: the CPU will read this value.

**Long answer**: there are couple of assumptions we need to clarify:

1. what CPU architecture we're talking about?  Some architectures (like x86 and x64) can operate on misaligned values, while some others (like ARM) can't.  This means that the values in ARM can only be accessed at addresses that are `N * sizeof(primitive-value-type)`, where N is integer.  The memory management functions and compilers know about it, so they automatically align allocations on these platforms.
2. the memory management functions use some memory themselves for housekeeping.  This means that the application will not see consecutive allocations like the question describes.  Depending on the exact heap manager used, the first allocation will be a few pointer sizes worth away from 0, and the next allocation will return the address that is at least several pointer sizes after the end of the first allocation.
3. as long as the above conditions hold true, reading across multiple pages is completely transparent to the application.  The processor is doing the linear->physical address translation behind the scene and calls back the OS when the page needs to be pulled into the physical memory.  But this is not something the application (generally) can and should be aware of.
4. somebody else might reflect on 64-byte pages.  I'm not aware of a platform with pages smaller than 4kB, but I assume the 64-byte page size in question was used for demonstration purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

Page boundaries are only meaningful for memory allocation and logical address translation. The application does not see page boundaries (other than when allocating pages). All the application sees is a continuous logical address space.